# Identify rows in a python DataFrame that are equal ...

Tags: python, dataframe, rows

I have a large DataFrame (called AllDTrades) with a lot of security trades, like this one:

```
    trd_exctn_dt    ascii_rptd_vol_tx   rptd_pr    yld_pt       sttl_dt
1   2018-07-02      150000.0            98.6100    4.476914     7/5/2018 
....
```

Now, I need to find a function that is able to tell me how many times a specific trade is located in the DataFrame and where in the DataFrame. So I need to ask something in the lines of this (this does not work of course):

```
AllDTrades.loc[AllDTrades==SpecificTrade],
```

where

SpecificTrade is a trade, lets say this one:

```
2018-07-02      150000.0            98.6100    4.476914     7/5/2018
```

So, I need to find out if SpecificTrade 
1) is part of AllDTrades
2) the location of the trade in AllDTrades
3) also, if there are more than one trade in AllDTrades like SpecificTrade, I need to know where all of them are located in AllDTrades

Is that possible ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Cheers, Jesper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use[`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for column `index` of values of indices of `AllDTrades` wit equal values like `SpecificTrade`, also if no parameter `on` it merge by all columns:

```
print (AllDTrades)
  trd_exctn_dt  ascii_rptd_vol_tx  rptd_pr    yld_pt   sttl_dt
1   2018-07-02           150000.0    98.61  4.476914  7/5/2018
2   2018-07-03           290000.0    98.61  4.476914  7/5/2018
3   2018-07-02           150000.0    98.61  4.476914  7/5/2018


SpecificTrade = AllDTrades.iloc[[0]]
print (SpecificTrade)
 trd_exctn_dt  ascii_rptd_vol_tx  rptd_pr    yld_pt   sttl_dt
1   2018-07-02           150000.0    98.61  4.476914  7/5/2018

df = AllDTrades.reset_index().merge(SpecificTrade)
print (df)
   index trd_exctn_dt  ascii_rptd_vol_tx  rptd_pr    yld_pt   sttl_dt
0      1   2018-07-02           150000.0    98.61  4.476914  7/5/2018
1      3   2018-07-02           150000.0    98.61  4.476914  7/5/2018
```

---

```
vals = df['index']
print (vals)
0    1
1    3
Name: index, dtype: int64

print (AllDTrades.loc[vals])
  trd_exctn_dt  ascii_rptd_vol_tx  rptd_pr    yld_pt   sttl_dt
1   2018-07-02           150000.0    98.61  4.476914  7/5/2018
3   2018-07-02           150000.0    98.61  4.476914  7/5/2018
```

Comment: Thank you very much jezrael ! Not in a million years, I would have thought that a combination of reset_index() and merge would be the key here ... Thank you, Cheers, Jesper.